# Apache Beam Python SDK upgrade issue

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I just made an upgrade from `apache-beam==2.5.0` to `apache-beam[gcp]==2.11.0`, and now I'm getting the error posted below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 178, in execute
    op.finish()
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 549, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
    def finish(self):
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 550, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
    with self.scoped_finish_state:
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 551, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish
    self.dofn_runner.finish()
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 758, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.finish
    self._invoke_bundle_method(self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_finish_bundle)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 752, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 777, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
    raise_with_traceback(new_exn)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 750, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method
    bundle_method()
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 361, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle
    def invoke_finish_bundle(self):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 364, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle
    self.output_processor.finish_bundle_outputs(
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 887, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.finish_bundle_outputs
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 130, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
    self.update_counters_start(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 110, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.ConsumerSet.update_counters_start
    self.opcounter.update_from(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 195, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.update_from
    self.do_sample(windowed_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 213, in apache_beam.runners.worker.opcounters.OperationCounters.do_sample
    self.coder_impl.get_estimated_size_and_observables(windowed_value))
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 991, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
    def get_estimated_size_and_observables(self, value, nested=False):
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1007, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
    self._windows_coder.estimate_size(value.windows, nested=True))
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 791, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.SequenceCoderImpl.estimate_size
    self.get_estimated_size_and_observables(value))
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 805, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.SequenceCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
    self._elem_coder.get_estimated_size_and_observables(
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 145, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables
    return self.estimate_size(value, nested), []
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 487, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.IntervalWindowCoderImpl.estimate_size
    typed_value = value
TypeError: Cannot convert GlobalWindow to apache_beam.utils.windowed_value._IntervalWindowBase [while running 'output_timings/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles']
```

I have some code to store the pipeline result on Google Cloud Storage like so:

```
## OUTPUT
json_output = joint_data | "json_output" >> beam.ParDo(WriteAsJSON())
output = json_output | "output" >> WriteToText(known_args.output + "/dataset.json-lines")


result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

Where `WriteAsJSON` is something like that:

```
@th.with_input_types(th.Any)
@th.with_output_types(six.text_type)
class WriteAsJSON(beam.DoFn):

    @checklist_item("variable day.mean_pages")
    def process(self, element):
        (visitor_address, joint_dict) =  element

        visit_variables = joint_dict['visit']
        day_mean_pages = joint_dict['day.mean_pages']

        d = {}

        if (len(day_mean_pages) == 0) or (len(visit_variables) == 0):
            return []

        visit_variables=visit_variables[0]

        visitor_country_datum = joint_dict['country']


        for (var_name, var_value) in visit_variables.items():
            d[var_name] = var_value

        # for (var_name, var_value) in day_mean_pages.items():
        #     d['day.' + var_name ] = var_value
        d['day.mean_pages'] = day_mean_pages[0]

        # Just merge and dump everything
        d['visitor_address'] = visitor_address

        if len(visitor_country_datum) > 0:
            d['visitor_iso2'] = visitor_country_datum[0]['iso2']
            d['ip.geographical_distance'] = visitor_country_datum[0]['ip.geographical_distance']
        else:
            d['visitor_iso2'] = None
            d['ip.geographical_distance'] = None


        s = json.dumps(d)
        return [s]
```

Has something changed on the `apache-beam` API that makes this breaks? I have been reading the release notes but I haven't seen anything about. Any help will be very welcome. Thanks in advance.

I checked that question [How to create a Dataflow pipeline from Pub/Sub to GCS in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745869/how-to-create-a-dataflow-pipeline-from-pub-sub-to-gcs-in-python), and tried to revert to `apache-beam[gcp]==2.9.0` but it didn't work for my case.

Comment: For what it's worth `sudo git apache-beam[gcp]==2.9.0` did work for me.  I'm running this from within the Google Console.

Comment: I'll confirm this is an issue.  The individual steps seem to complete, but the overall (batch) job itself doesn't tear itself down.  That could become very costly on unattended Dataflow jobs, since even the number of VMs doesn't scale down.

Comment: jimmarens, to install apache beam you can use `pip install apache-beam[gcp]==2.9.0` more here https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/#download-and-install

Comment: working on SDK v 2.16, continue to get same error