# Apache Beam per-user session windows are unmerged

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have an app that has users; each user uses our app for something like 10-40 minutes per go and I would like to count the distribution/occurrences of events happing per-such-session, based on specific events having happened (e.g. "this user converted", "this user had a problem last session", "this user had a successful last session").

(After this I'd like to count these higher-level events per day, but that's a separate question)

For this I've been looking into session windows; but all [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#setting-your-pcollections-windowing-function) seem geared towards global session windows, but I'd like to create them per-user (which is also a natural partitioning).

I'm having trouble finding docs (python preferred) on how to do this. Could you point me in the right direction?

Or in other words: **How do I create per-user per-session windows that can output more structured (enriched) events?**

### What I have

```
class DebugPrinter(beam.DoFn):
  """Just prints the element with logging"""
  def process(self, element, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
    _, x = element
    logging.info(">>> Received %s %s with window=%s", x['jsonPayload']['value'], x['timestamp'], window)
    yield element

def sum_by_event_type(user_session_events):
  logging.debug("Received %i events: %s", len(user_session_events), user_session_events)
  d = {}
  for key, group in groupby(user_session_events, lambda e: e['jsonPayload']['value']):
    d[key] = len(list(group))
  logging.info("After counting: %s", d)
  return d

# ...

by_user = valid \
  | 'keyed_on_user_id'      >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['jsonPayload']['userId'], x))

session_gap = 5 * 60 # [s]; 5 minutes

user_sessions = by_user \
  | 'user_session_window'   >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.Sessions(session_gap),
                                               timestamp_combiner=beam.window.TimestampCombiner.OUTPUT_AT_EOW) \
  | 'debug_printer'         >> beam.ParDo(DebugPrinter()) \
  | beam.CombinePerKey(sum_by_event_type)
```

### What it outputs

```
INFO:root:>>> Received event_1 2019-03-12T08:54:29.200Z with window=[1552380869.2, 1552381169.2)
INFO:root:>>> Received event_2 2019-03-12T08:54:29.200Z with window=[1552380869.2, 1552381169.2)
INFO:root:>>> Received event_3 2019-03-12T08:54:30.400Z with window=[1552380870.4, 1552381170.4)
INFO:root:>>> Received event_4 2019-03-12T08:54:36.300Z with window=[1552380876.3, 1552381176.3)
INFO:root:>>> Received event_5 2019-03-12T08:54:38.100Z with window=[1552380878.1, 1552381178.1)
```

So as you can see; the Session() window doesn't expand the Window, but groups only very close events together... What's being done wrong?

Comment: How about adding a ParDo before your windowing transform ? This ParDo would create Key Value pairs from the incoming stream where the Key would be the user Id . So we have a bunch of <UserId-Value> pairs that we feed into the window for aggregation [every x minutes] . You can then group by or combine the output of the window per key [user id]

Comment: It's already there I think; it's called `keyed_on_user_id`.

Comment: Please let me also know if you find this out. Thanks !

Comment: The Session window should group a series of consecutive events separated by a specified gap size, per key. You have given a 5 minute gap, so the values should be all the items for a key where either this is the first time a item is seen for this key or the last time a key was seen was more than 5 mins in the past. The values will be grouped until such time as 5 mins has passed with again no value being seen for that key.

Comment: But isn't the window then supposed to expand to encompass the latest values seen? Because the key (user id) has more than two events in that window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it to work by adding a Group By Key transform after the windowing. You have assigned keys to the records but haven't actually grouped them together by key and session windowing (which works per-key) does not know that these events need to be merged together.

To confirm this I did a reproducible example with some in-memory dummy data (to isolate Pub/Sub from the problem and be able to test it more quickly). All five events will have the same key or `user_id` but they will "arrive" sequentially 1, 2, 4 and 8 seconds apart from each other. As I use `session_gap` of 5 seconds I expect the first 4 elements to be merged into the same session. The 5th event will take 8 seconds after the 4th one so it has to be relegated to the next session (gap over 5s). Data is created like this:

```py
data = [{'user_id': 'Thanos', 'value': 'event_{}'.format(event), 'timestamp': time.time() + 2**event} for event in range(5)]
```

We use `beam.Create(data)` to initialize the pipeline and `beam.window.TimestampedValue` to assign the "fake" timestamps. Again, we are just simulating streaming behavior with this. After that, we create the key-value pairs thanks to the `user_id` field, we window into `window.Sessions` and, we add the missing `beam.GroupByKey()` step. Finally, we log the results with a slightly modified version of `DebugPrinter`:. The pipeline now looks like this:

```py
events = (p
  | 'Create Events' >> beam.Create(data) \
  | 'Add Timestamps' >> beam.Map(lambda x: beam.window.TimestampedValue(x, x['timestamp'])) \
  | 'keyed_on_user_id'      >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['user_id'], x))
  | 'user_session_window'   >> beam.WindowInto(window.Sessions(session_gap),
                                             timestamp_combiner=window.TimestampCombiner.OUTPUT_AT_EOW) \
  | 'Group' >> beam.GroupByKey()
  | 'debug_printer'         >> beam.ParDo(DebugPrinter()))
```

where `DebugPrinter` is:

```py
class DebugPrinter(beam.DoFn):
  """Just prints the element with logging"""
  def process(self, element, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
    for x in element[1]:
      logging.info(">>> Received %s %s with window=%s", x['value'], x['timestamp'], window)

    yield element
```

If we test this without grouping by key we get the same behavior:

```py
INFO:root:>>> Received event_0 1554117323.0 with window=[1554117323.0, 1554117328.0)
INFO:root:>>> Received event_1 1554117324.0 with window=[1554117324.0, 1554117329.0)
INFO:root:>>> Received event_2 1554117326.0 with window=[1554117326.0, 1554117331.0)
INFO:root:>>> Received event_3 1554117330.0 with window=[1554117330.0, 1554117335.0)
INFO:root:>>> Received event_4 1554117338.0 with window=[1554117338.0, 1554117343.0)
```

But after adding it, the windows now work as expected. Events 0 to 3 are merged together in an extended 12s session window. Event 4 belongs to a separate 5s session.

```py
INFO:root:>>> Received event_0 1554118377.37 with window=[1554118377.37, 1554118389.37)
INFO:root:>>> Received event_1 1554118378.37 with window=[1554118377.37, 1554118389.37)
INFO:root:>>> Received event_3 1554118384.37 with window=[1554118377.37, 1554118389.37)
INFO:root:>>> Received event_2 1554118380.37 with window=[1554118377.37, 1554118389.37)
INFO:root:>>> Received event_4 1554118392.37 with window=[1554118392.37, 1554118397.37)
```

Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/199a91a49c90f9248d636f95e5b74e4b)

Two additional things worth mentioning. The first one is that, even if running this locally in a single machine with the DirectRunner, records can come unordered (event_3 is processed before event_2 in my case). This is done on purpose to simulate distributed processing as documented [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/).

The last one is that if you get a stack trace like this:

```py
TypeError: Cannot convert GlobalWindow to apache_beam.utils.windowed_value._IntervalWindowBase [while running 'Write Results/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles']
```

downgrade from 2.10.0/2.11.0 SDK to 2.9.0. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54791913/6121516) for example.

Comment: Thanks @Guillem — I've accepted this as the answer, but due to the experienced buggyness and lack of community around Beam, I've moved to Flink. Stats for me/someome who's never worked with either before: 16h Beam, failed to do the above, 6h Flink, succeeded with session windows in first try and could ALSO flush/purge the window and control the window 'lookahead' based on data. – Henrik just now