# How to wait with 1h buffer in apache-beam and then push the date?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

[image: Events timeline]

I am gathering information about the flights. Maximal length of the flight is 10h. I am getting tracking information in about every 1 minute. Events order is disturb during processing in apache beam. After merging all the data I want to push it to BigQuery and discard the data so it doesn't consume memory.

I have 2 strategies how to do this:

1) Wait 1h and if there is no new data coming push it to BQ

2) In every 15 minutes run my own algorithm which verify if data is complete.

I want to go with 1) cause it's simpler. Can my code be correct?:

```py
models = (xmls | beam.FlatMap(process_xmls))
tracking_informations = models | beam.ParDo(FilterTI())
grouped_tis = tracking_informations | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(10 * 3600), trigger=AfterProcessingTime(1 * 3600), accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING) | beam.GroupByKey() | "push and merge to BQ"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your use case and the desired approach -grouping all events belonging to the same flight together until you find a gap of inactivity- this seems like a perfect fit for [Session windows](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#provided-windowing-functions). In the example, you should be using the flight identifier (`f1`,`f2` and so on as the key) and specifying a gap of 1 hour. If no new events are observed during that time the session will be terminated.

You can use them with `beam.WindowInto(window.Sessions(session_gap))` and you can find a full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55475199/6121516) (don't forget to add the Group By Key step to actually merge the events together in a single session).

Comment: I was reading about session window before... But after reading your post I will give it a try!