# Why in apache-beam I get error: "TypeError: Cannot convert GlobalWindow to _IntervalWindowBase when using SessionWindow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When I use session window with 1h gap and after processing million of messages I get error in logs, probably just for some rows:

```py
TypeError: Cannot convert GlobalWindow to apache_beam.utils.windowed_value._IntervalWindowBase
```

Code:

```py
grouped_tis = tracking_informations | beam.WindowInto(window.Sessions(session_window_gap)) | beam.GroupByKey() | beam.ParDo(MergeTI()) | "TI model -> json" >> beam.Map(jsons.dump)
```

Full stack:
https://pastebin.com/pqA5pMay

Comment: I think this was affecting a couple SDK versions such as 2.10.0 and 2.11.0. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54791913/6121516)

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I stopped using Dataflow, cause I have some problems with using Window.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is experiencing same problem, I solve this problem insert `beam.WindowInto(beam.window.GlobalWindows())` between `beam.WindowInto(NONGLOBALWINDOW) | beam.GroupByKey()` and other Ptransform that causes problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because some code (such as `MergeTI`) is returning elements in `GlobalWindow` while the `PCollection` has a different window set: `beam.WindowInto(window.Sessions(session_window_gap))`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue as well, Seems the only thing that would fix it was to insert:

```py
beam.WindowInto(beam.window.GlobalWindows())
```

right before:

```py
beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, it is because BigQuery table actually wants a `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z` timestamp but I passed a `%Y-%m-%d` date. I don't know why, but I'm shocked.